# Determine chessboard dimensions in pixels

Tags: c, opencv, camera-calibration

Similar to calibrating a single camera 2D image with a chessboard, I wish to determine the width/height of the chessboard (or of a single square) in pixels.

I have a camera aimed vertically at the ground, ensured to be perfectly level with the surface below. I am using the camera to determine the translation between consequtive frames (successfully achieved using fourier phase correlation), at the moment my result returns the translation in pixels, however I would like to use techniques similar to calibration, where I move the camera over the chessboard which is flat on the ground, to automatically determine the size of the chessboard in pixels, relative to my image height and width.

Knowing the size of the chessboard in millimetres, I can then convert a pixel unit to a real-world-unit in millimetres, ie, 1 pixel will represent a distance proportional to the height of the camera above the ground. This will allow me to convert a translation in pixels to a translation in millimetres, recalibrating every time I change the height of the camera.

What would be the recommended way of achieving this? Surely it must be simpler than single camera 2D calibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV can give you the position of the chessboard's corners with [`cv::findChessboardCorners()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-findchessboardcorners).

I'm not sure if the perspective distortion will affect your calculations, but if the chessboard is perfectly aligned beneath the camera, it should work.

Comment: Ah thanks I will give this a go. The output array of the corners, is this a pixel location (x,y)? of the outer most edge of the chessboard, finding four corners essentially?

Comment: Worked perfectly, use the co-ordinates of the chessboard corners to determine the distance in pixels between each corner. Therefore knowing the distance between corners in millimetres can convert a translation that i measure in pixels into a real-world translation in millimetres.

Comment: Also doing a check to ensure the distance in pixels between each corner is relatively equal, to ensure the chessboard is perfectly level with the camera for calibration.

Comment: OpenCV is pretty awesome. There's also a simple Python wrapper for OpenCV, which simplifies the whole API greatly: http://www.simplecv.org/docs/SimpleCV.html#i/SimpleCV.ImageClass.Image/findChessboard

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea so don't hit me.. but maybe using the natural contrast of the chessboard?

"At some point it will switch from bright to dark pixels and that should happen (can't remember number of columns on chessboard) times." should be a doable algorithm.